# npyscreen - switchForm(formid) error

Tags: python-3.x, python-curses, npyscreen

I am using npyscreen and i would like to understand how the switchForm method works. 
I did a small example that I took from the documentation and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142002/npyscreen-errors-raised-with-the-use-of-npsappmanaged-switchformformid-with) (that didn't answer my question).
My Code:

```
import npyscreen
import sys

class myEmployeeForm(npyscreen.ActionForm):
   def afterEditing(self):
      self.parentApp.setNextForm('Second')

   def create(self):
      self.myName = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name='Name')
      self.myDepartment = self.add(npyscreen.TitleSelectOne, scroll_exit=True, max_height=3, name='Department', values = ['Department 1', 'Department 2', 'Department 3'])
   self.myDate        = self.add(npyscreen.TitleDateCombo, name='Date Employed')

class secondOne(npyscreen.ActionForm):
  def afterEditing(self):
     self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

  def create(self):
     self.myName        = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name='Name')
     self.myDepartment = self.add(npyscreen.TitleSelectOne, scroll_exit=True, max_height=3, name='Department', values = ['Department 1', 'Department 2', 'Department 3'])
     self.myDate        = self.add(npyscreen.TitleDateCombo, name='Date Employed')
     self.add_handlers({"^Q": sys.exit, "^T": self.changingForm('Second')})

  def changingForm(self, name):
     self.parentApp.switchForm(name)

class MyApplication(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
   def onStart(self):
    self.addForm('MAIN', myEmployeeForm, name='New Employee')
    self.addForm('Second', secondOne, name='New start')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  TestApp = MyApplication().run()
```

Can someone explain to me why I get this error :

```
File "/home/MyName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/npyscreen/apNPSApplicationManaged.py", line 81, in switchForm
self._THISFORM.editing = False
AttributeError: 'MyApplication' object has no attribute '_THISFORM'
```

Thank you for your support :)

Comment: For more information visit:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68580656/npyscreen-how-do-i-edit-other-screens-forms-and-customize-it-with-widgets
```

Answer (score 0):

My error is linked more to python than npyscreen.
See here [enter link description here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/npyscreen/ogQEquo8CNc)
Thank you